# Serving static HTML from CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, serverside-javascript, couchapp

I've got a CouchDB server up and running serving basic API requests.  Overall it works well because users can GET/POST/PUT etc. to the host 'api.example.com'.  The only issue is that if a user does a GET request for `'/'`, they get the `{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.0.2"}`.

Is there anyway to serve a single static HTML page or even an HTTP redirect for the root?  That way I could redirect users to the API documentation.

I'm vaguely familiar with [Couchapp](http://couchapp.org) but it seems like overkill for such a simple task.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `_rewrites` already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want a vhost/rewrite rule. They are pretty easy. Basically you tell CouchDB that queries to "www.example.com" should go directly to the rewriter. The rewriter will serve anything that you specify in the design document.

Jan Lehnardt wrote up good instructions in the Couchbase blog post, [Nice URLs](http://blog.couchbase.com/whats-new-in-apache-couchdb-0-11-part-one-nice-urls).